# Select on insert

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, spring-jdbc

I've a query regarding Oracle SQL DB.

We are inserting 1 million records into db using one insert statement (in combination with select statement).

```
INSERT INTO <TABLE_NAME> VALUES(<COL1,COL2,COL3>,....etc)
SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME> // this select query retrieves 1 million records
```

Upon execution of insert, is there a way to get back all the records?

Basically,I don't want to execute another select statement to fetch these records. Instead I'm trying to find an optimized way.

Answer (score 0):

I would first run the select statement to create a private temporary table. This creates an in-memory table and doesn't actually run to disk.

```
CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TABLE as
SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME> // this select query retrieves 1 million records
```

Then run your insert from the temporary table. This write the data just once to the place you need it.
And the data is still available to use in the temporary table to use in the session.
When the session is closed the data in the temporary table is no longer available.